# Method in a case branch of a switch statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement

Is there a way of using some methods directly in case branch like I have in this code?

```
string strLink = txtLink.Text;
switch(strLink)
{
     case strLink.StartsWith("www"):
          strLink = "http://www." + strLink.Substring(3);
          break;
     case !strLink.StartsWith("www"):
          strLink = "http://www." + strLink;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but you could do something like:

```
string strLink = txtLink.Text;
string firstThreeChars = strLink.Substring(0,3);

switch(firstThreeChars)
{
    case "www":
        strLink = "http://www." + strLink.Substring(3);
        break;
    default:
        strLink = "http://www." + strLink;
        break;
}
```

However, it looks to me like there may be some logic issues with your code.  What happens if txtLink.Text is `www.google.com`?  Isn't your output going to be `http://www..google.com`?

Having said all that, if these are your only two cases, I would suggest something more like:

```
string strLink = "google.com";
string newLink = "http://" + (strLink.StartsWith("www.") ? strLink : "www." + strLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the expression in the `case` part of a `switch` statement should be compile-time constant or `default`. This could be constants, enum values or expressions containing things above.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the C# spec on `switch` statements is pretty limited. What you'd be looking for is probably the (arguably not as nice) `if...else if` syntax. For good measure, that would be:

```
string strLink = txtLink.Text;
if (strLink.StartsWith("www"))
{
    strLink = "http://www." + strLink.Substring(3);
}
else //if(!strLink.StartsWith("www")) this line is, of course, not necessary
     //                               since it's implied by the else, but that's
     //                               what it would be otherwise
{
    strLink = "http://www." + strLink;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew...yes probably the only way to go will be if/else statement. I was just wondering if there is any way to use in this case switch.

Answer (score 0):

Can not use different value type between switch condition and case blocks. If you have only two case, just use to `if statement`.

```
    string strLink = txtLink.Text;
    if (strLink.StartsWith("www"))
    {
        strLink = "http://www." + strLink.Substring(3);
    }
    else
    {
        strLink = "http://www." + strLink;
    }
```